# looking for a clean way to find relationships from a set of nodes

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have got a set of nodes and I would like to write a query to find every relationships which exist between these nodes.

Any recommendation?

My first attemp would be a MATCH a-[rel]-b WHERE... and my WHERE clause would be a OR of all the ids I have in my set of nodes.

Any better idea?

Comment: wouldn't a simple `MATCH (n)-[r]-(o) WHERE id(n) IN {ids} AND id(o) IN {ids} RETURN distinct(r)` work ?

Comment: Yes, but `distinct` is not needed, since Cypher would automatically filter out duplicate relationships from a single `MATCH` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these answers, I assume you will pass the ID list as a parameter named `ids`.

1. If you want to exclude relationships from a node to itself:

   ```
   MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)
   WHERE id(a) IN {ids} AND id(b) IN {ids} AND a <> b
   RETURN r;
   ```
2. If you want to include relationships from a node to itself:

   ```
   MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)
   WHERE id(a) IN {ids} AND id(b) IN {ids}
   RETURN r;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
MATCH (a)-[rel]-()
WHERE ID(a) IN {node_ids}
RETURN rel, ID(rel), type(rel), ID(startNode(rel)), ID(endNode(rel))
```

Here you'd be passing in a `node_ids` [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html) which would be an array.

Note also that using internal Neo4j IDs for long-term reference to nodes may break if Neo4j defragments the nodes.